# How to fix the error "'x' and 'w' must have the same length" in summarise_all()?

Tags: r, dplyr, anonymous-function, group-summaries

I want to use dplyr::summarise_all() and weighted.mean to calculate the weighted averages of many columns for each group.

I tried to directly use anonymous function, but it returned an error: 
'x' and 'w' must have the same length. I know I can use summarise() and weighted.mean, but in this way I need to specify all the column names, which is not what I want.

```
result = df%>%
  group_by(A)%>%
  summarise_all(function(x){weighted.mean(x, .$B)})
```

Here the data frame has group column A, weight column B and other columns. I expect to have weighted averages of other columns values by column B for each group in A. I hope I can do this using dplyr and weighted.mean, but I am OK with other available methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We dont' need `.$` as `.$` extract the whole column value instead of the values that corresponds to the grouping structure

```
df %>%
   group_by(A)%>%
   summarise_all(list(~ weighted.mean(., B)))
```

---

It can also be written without a lambda function (`~`) if we provide the parameters explicitly

```
df %>%
   group_by(A)%>%
   summarise_all(weighted.mean, w = B)
```

Comment: It seems these answers no longer work. Thoughts? For example: this returns the x and w must gave the same length error the OP mentioned: mtcars %>%
    group_by(am)%>%
    summarise_all(list(~ weighted.mean(., hp)))

Comment: @RickPack you may need `summarise(across(-B, ~ weighted.mean(.x, B)))`